# Sublime not recognize functions such as toBeTrue().

Tags: angularjs, typescript, mocha.js, chai, gulp-protractor

I'm trying to test if an element appears after a button is clicked. But sublime doesn't recognize any of the functions such as toBeTrue(), toBe(true) by showing red line. Here are the codes:

```
updAccDtlBtn.click().then(function() {

 expect(p.browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal('http://localhost:3000/myAccount');

 //A green field notifying success will be displayed
 var succUpdSpan = p.browser.element(p.By.cssContainingText('col-sm-offset-4','Account Details Successfully Updated'));

 expect(succUpdSpan.isPresent()).toBeTrue();

 });
```

Comment: Sorry for editing so many times and if the question is not too interesting. This is my first question on stackoverflow. :D

Answer (score 0):

The method `toBeTrue()` does not exist within protractor.
Instead of `toBeTrue()` you should use the method `toBeTruthy()`, like:

`expect(succUpdSpan.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();`

or

`expect(succUpdSpan.isPresent()).toEqual(true);`

Comment: It ends up because I'm was using chai and mocha, so I had to write something like 

`succUpdSpan.isPresent.to.eventually.be.true;`   or
`succUpdSpan.isPresent.to.eventually.equal(true);`

I was targeting the wrong documents....